# Auto generate only specific part from Json, not the whole json

Tags: flutter, dart, model

I am using https://app.quicktype.io to generate my model class. All I give this website is my JSON code. But, all I want is a list, which is called `data`, within this json file, not the whole JSON. What should I do?

[image: 'data' List, within json. Which I want]

[image: this picture shows that this json is NOT a list in itself]

Comment: just copy paste the JSON array from ``data`` key and paste on the website. You'll get what you're looking for !

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

**UserModel.dart** file:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

List<UserModel> userModelFromJson(String str) => List<UserModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => UserModel.fromJson(x)));

String userModelToJson(List<UserModel> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class UserModel {
    UserModel({
        @required this.id,
        @required this.email,
        @required this.firstName,
        @required this.lastName,
        @required this.avatar,
    });

    int id;
    String email;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String avatar;

    factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
        id: json["id"],
        email: json["email"],
        firstName: json["first_name"],
        lastName: json["last_name"],
        avatar: json["avatar"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "email": email,
        "first_name": firstName,
        "last_name": lastName,
        "avatar": avatar,
    };
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, you need to call ['data'] on decoded json like this: 

`List<UserModel> userModelFromJson(String str) => List<UserModel>.from((json.decode(str)['data'] as List).map((x) => UserModel.fromJson(x)));`

Comment: @eamirho3ein obviously this won't work if the structure of the data is different. And, yes you're correct